Adding username of SharePoint template instance to Header/Footer in Excel workbook
I've seen a few other similar questions on here and other forums, but this exact issue is not yet specifically addressed. I need to place the username in the footer of an excel worksheet. This is not the username of the original creator/author of the document. It was created as a form that is uploaded on SharePoint as a template. I need to see the username of whichever user who creates an instance of the template and saves to the desired SharePoint folder. Within SharePoint, there is a column "creator", that displays this on SharePoint. But the auditor of the forms wants to be able to print out a copy of the completed template with the username from each instance of the template being used.
I've tried using the following two sets of code. The first one always comes back with the original username of the person who created the form (me), even when I have someone else open the template and fill out their submission. the 2nd one only works on a local machine as I believe it is intended to display the username of the account logged into Windows.
Sub user()
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftFooter = "SUBMITTED BY: " & Application.UserName & " on " & Date
    End With
End Sub


Sub user()  
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftFooter = "SUBMITTED BY: " & Environ("Username") & " on " & Date
    End With
End Sub



"as a template" do you mean an actual *.dotx file?

No, not .dotx file, uploading an .xlsx file as a template in SharePoint for users to fill out instances of a form to submit for peer review and audit. These are forms for documenting periodic scheduled maintenance.

Since this is a form, can you add a place for the Creator to enter their name?  Low tech but should be fine...

That is exactly what I thought! All our other forms are like that. This one has been sent via email, but I suggested we upload submissions like other forms. Some other powers that be from the QA team don't share this commonsense approach. I was told, they can't know who submitted it just because a name was written in. "Anyone could write any name on the form." They want the footer to automatically grab the name from the meta data (digital fingerprint).

Someone could also ask another person to upload a file for them...   I would prefer the name be entered in the form over having it pulled from SP.

In the Navy, it was called "gundecking." When someone falsifies maintenance paperwork by changing results to show a passing value or simply to present as though maintenance was completed but never actually done. No amount of software coding can totally prevent this from happening. At some point techs have to be trusted to do their work. This is what QC/QA is intended to do - verify/validate data by conducting calibrations and audits.

Borrowing from this answer. If you need the "Creator" property from SharePoint, you have to extract the SharePoint's metadata, which can be accessed through VBA via the MSXML2.XMLHTTP object.
Not tested as I don't have a SharePoint site handy, but should be something like:
url = "https://yoursharepointsite/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/site/library/file.xlsx')/ListItemAllFields"

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", url, False
http.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose"
http.Send

Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)

creator = Json("d")("Author")("Title")


Thank you for geting me stared in the right direction. I am not a programmer. Should that code be nested inside the example i gave above in my question?

Having to specify the filename in the code of the file itself won't work as each instance of the template is saved with a unique naming convention ([equipment-S/N][Date][Location]): GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/site/library/file.xlsx')
